# Limit Cycle Analysis - State Space Rep. to Polar Coordinates Question

Tags: polar-coordinates, transformation, nonlinear-dynamics

I am trying to follow an example that does not show how a set of dynamics equations is converted to polar coordinates:

$\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{x_2}{x_1}$

$\frac{d}{dt}\tan\theta=(\frac{1}{\cos\theta})^{2}\dot\theta$$=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{x_2}{x_1}=\frac{1}{x_1^2}$$(\dot{x_2}{x_1}$$-{x_2}$$\dot{x_1})$

After which point I insert my dynamics and cancel some terms to get...

$=\frac{1}{x_1^2}(-{x_1^2}-{x_2^2})$

$=\frac{1}{x_1^2}(-r^2)$

*And now for the last part which I do not follow:*

$\bbox[yellow]{=\frac{1}{x_1^2}(-r^2)=-(\frac{1}{\cos\theta})^2}$

So that, finally,

$\dot\theta=-1$

Can anyone please help me understand the part in yellow?

Edit: Any of these systems should produce clockwise limit cycles where $\dot\theta=-1$.
[See image for examples: Slotine's Applied Nonlinear Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDfVj.png)

I still just don't get the part in yellow.

Comment: Your question lacks clarity since a huge part of the problem is not stated. What system do you consider? Where is it coming from? Please provide a link to it if possible.

Comment: Edited to add some example systems.  They all get to the same point though, which is the step highlighted in yellow.

Comment: The post is still unclear. Please provide the system you are considering and also define all the notation. For instance, $r$ is not defined.

Comment: It was polar coordinate so that r^2 = x1^2 + x2^2.  The part i didn't understand was algebra/trig.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the step in yellow... Needed Wolfram Alpha for both of these steps lol

$=\frac{1}{x_1^2}(-{x_1^2}-{x_2^2})$

$=-\frac{x_2^2}{x_1^2}-1$

$=-(\tan\theta)^2-1$

$=-(\frac{1}{\cos\theta})^2$

$\dot\theta=-1$